# Fire Timer Tick from Baseform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, timer

I have a base Form with a Timer that simply should show the time in all Forms that inherit from it.
`MainForm` (which inherits from `BaseForm`) does this job very well.

From `MainForm`, I open other Forms which inherit from `Baseform`.
In these Forms, the time won't change after the Form is opened.
The work is the same in all derived Forms. Each Timer Tick should update the Time in a Label in the active Form.

I have tried Property Binding and adding the event in each form. Nothing works properly.

I am thankful for any hint :-)

Here i have the code from my BaseForm

```
Partial Class FrmBasisNew
    Inherits Form
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Wird vom Windows Form-Designer benötigt.
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'Hinweis: Die folgende Prozedur ist für den Windows Form-Designer erforderlich.
    'Das Bearbeiten ist mit dem Windows Form-Designer möglich.  
    'Das Bearbeiten mit dem Code-Editor ist nicht möglich.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(FrmBasisNew))
        Me.Tim_Uhrzeit = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
        Me.PNLTOP = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Me.lblTime = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.PNLTOP.SuspendLayout()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Tim_Uhrzeit
        '
        Me.Tim_Uhrzeit.Interval = 1000
        '
        'PNLTOP
        '
        Me.PNLTOP.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        Me.PNLTOP.BackColor = Global.KundF.My.MySettings.Default.glUserDefinedBackColor
        Me.PNLTOP.Controls.Add(Me.lblTime)
        Me.PNLTOP.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top
        Me.PNLTOP.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.PNLTOP.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        Me.PNLTOP.Name = "PNLTOP"
        Me.PNLTOP.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(788, 58)
        Me.PNLTOP.TabIndex = 2
        '
        'lblTime
        '
        Me.lblTime.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Global.KundF.My.MySettings.Default, "glUserdefinedTime", True, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
        Me.lblTime.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right
        Me.lblTime.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.lblTime.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText
        Me.lblTime.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(724, 0)
        Me.lblTime.Name = "lblTime"
        Me.lblTime.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(64, 58)
        Me.lblTime.TabIndex = 6
        Me.lblTime.Text = Global.KundF.My.MySettings.Default.glUserdefinedTime
        '
        'FrmBasisNew
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(788, 716)
        Me.ControlBox = False
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PNLTOP)
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.MinimizeBox = False
        Me.Name = "FrmBasisNew"
        Me.ShowIcon = False
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
        Me.PNLTOP.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents PNLTOP As Panel
    Protected WithEvents Tim_Uhrzeit As Timer
    Friend WithEvents lblTime As Label
End Class
```

Then the Code for The BaseForm

```
Public Class FrmBasisNew

    Private Sub Tim_Uhrzeit_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tim_Uhrzeit.Tick
        SetTime()
    End Sub
    Public Overridable Sub SetTime()
        Me.lblTime.Text = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss").ToString
    End Sub


End Class
```

Now, the DesignerCode for my Mainform

Comment: You should really show your code. Note that if you start a Timer in the constructor of the Base Form, you'll see the effects of the Timer's ticking even at Design-Time. E.g., if you show the date/time value in a Control in the Base Form, the derived Forms will show the live effect (you'll see the time change at Design-Time).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your Answer.
I try to post my code as good, as i can.
[code]

Comment: Where is the Timer started? (set `Me.lblTime.Text = Date.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss")`). Call `Tim_Uhrzeit.Start()`  in the Constructor of `FrmBasisNew`.

Comment: something is wrong with my subform. I don't know what is wrong BUT if i open an other subform it works.The joke of it's all is, that in the second Subform i do nothing with the Timer. I neighter enable the timer nor i start the timer. I am Confused.

Comment: There's nothing you have to do in your derived Form classes. The Timer belongs to the Base Form. It's either ticking or it's not. I don't see you starting the Timer anywhere, so it's not ticking. As mentioned, just start that Timer in the Constructor of the Base From. All the derived Forms will show the time in the Label. The Label's text is shown using the Base Form method, the derived Forms do nothing.

Comment: It is wired. I have the Timer_Tick Method in my Baseform. For Testing i give a debug Message with the form Name and i can see, that the Tick works for some forms and for one form it work not. That is, what confuse me.And it works without the Start Method of the timer!

Comment: what can the Timer prevent from Ticking in a form? Nevertheless the other functions (Buttons etc) working well. But the Timer.... arghhhh

Comment: I guess, i have found the problem... now i need a proper solution :-( I need to refresh the control on my subform to show the time changes. On all the other forms the refresh is automatic. What can a control prevent from automatic refresh?